# Custom bash prompt bugs at end of line

Tags: bash, prompt

I made a custom bash prompt, but after a few characters it deletes the whole line and enters my text on empty line.

Here's my prompt code:

```bash
PS1="\e[0;34m•\e[0m \u\e[0;34m~\e[0mcatshell \e[0;34m\w\e[0m : "
```

Comment: It works fine here. Looks like `• michael~catshell ~ :`

Comment: There is nothing in your prompt that causes cursor movement, deleting or overwriting characters, adding a newline, etc. I'm thinking the issue isn't your prompt.